# Postgresql, made domain named 'name', how can I delete it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

In Postgresql, I made user domain named 'name', and I don't know how to delete it

```
postgres=# create domain name char(20) not null;
CREATE DOMAIN
postgres=# drop domain name;
ERROR:  "name" is not a domain
```

How can I delete this domain?

Comment: use double quotes: `drop domain "name";`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Quotes only won't help [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5085a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add schema (probably `public`):

```
DROP DOMAIN public.name;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5085a)**</kbd>

Alternatively use `pgAdmin`, find `name`, right-click and `DELETE/DROP...`:

[image]